# Newtonian gravity gradient

Tags: differential-operators

Could someone explain to me why the gradient operator in $x$ below "consumes" the square of the norm from the denominator and minus sign? How are the two expressions equivalent?

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-G\int \frac{x-x'}{\|x-x'\|^3}\rho(x')d^3x'=\nabla[G\int\frac{\rho(x')}{\|x-x'\|}d^3x'] $$

$x$ and $x'$ are vectors of course. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working in summation convention, we can calculate
$$ \begin{align}
\left[ \nabla \lVert x-a \rVert^n \right]_i &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} ((x_j-a_j)(x_j-a_j))^{n/2} \\
&= 2\delta_{ik}(x_k-a_k) \frac{n}{2} ((x_j-a_j)(x_j-a_j))^{n/2-1} \\
&= n(x_i-a_i) \lVert x-a \rVert^{n-2},
\end{align} $$
and putting $n=-1$,
$$\nabla \frac{1}{\lVert x-a \rVert} = - \frac{x-a}{\lVert x-a \rVert^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\nabla \| \mathbf{x}\| = \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}$$
(of course we should justify why $\nabla$ and $\int$ commute)

Comment: Great, but what about the minus sign? Where did it go?

Comment: You apply the chain rule: $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \|\mathbf{x}\| \mapsto 1/\|\mathbf{x}\|$.